# How to validate calendar control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, calendar, controls

I'm using Asp.net and c# as my back end and I want to validate my check_in and check_out date in such a way that it the check_in is not before check_out and also check_in and check_out calendar controls cannot be blank, thanks.

.aspx page

```
<asp:Calendar ID="checkin" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>

<asp:Calendar ID="checkout" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            if (checkin.SelectedDate > checkout.SelectedDate)
            {
               // Not Valid
            }
```